# Typescript: Start with one type but end up with another type after declaring the object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Sorry for not knowing the exact TS terms for this. But how do I achieve this behavior:

```
// example type (coming from a package)
type LocaleErrorMessages = {
    required?: () => string | string
    email?: () => string | string
    passwords?: () => string | string
}

const DanishErrorMessages: LocaleErrorMessages = {
    email: () => 'Tjek om du har skrevet din e-mail korrekt',
    passwords: () => "Kodeordet lever ikke op til kravene"
}


DanishErrorMessages.email() // do NOT want this to Error
DanishErrorMessages.required() //  want this to Error
```

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIYBsIFEBOm6YLIQDOhSA5kVALxQDeAsAFBTNSYQCOArgJZsAmAfgBcUABQBKKgD4ohYJm4A7UlAA+s+UtKMWUCAFsk3FMLGTKMuQuVqN17UxZgkxAO64+hUxOl2ttqy1GAF9GRgQ4RTkoABEkRW5CAAssHHwiEnJCEXhkNFTcAmIyCmp6R2YDIxQRHwsoAHIAFQArCABrKDh9KD5OKCSkTFl2tgA3CGBepT0AWkNjKHbcNnbgBoAaHScXQndMT1rzGQAiAGk4PggPSag0CeHudvboODAoYEXRpAnFCBOQmEGIw4glkgV0sUsgA6KrGHwAegRvTgUAAcgB5JpQVzxKbAJKJD6oiEg+KJFLYQoZEqEaFsLi8CB8RHInF4j6EwjEqCkhhAA).

### Update

My example was a little too simple

```
// External package type (like StringLocale from Yup)
interface ILocaleErrorMessages {
    required?: () => string;
    email?: () => string;
    passwords?: () => string;
    min: ({ min: number } & MessageParams ) => string,
}
```

Comment: Just use extra function for inference. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/NBRJ4N)

Comment: Why not remove the `?`s on `LocaleErrorMessages`? Then you'll get the error in the place where it was caused: the missing field on `DanishErrorMessages`.

Comment: That is just to show the example @Thomas - the types comes from another package

Answer (score 1):

use generics

```
LocaleErrorMessages<T extends object> = {
  [k in keyof T]?: Func | string
)
```

Comment: This is a fine suggestion and covers my example. Unfortunately my example did not cover the cases where the functions takes arguments.

`Type '({ min }: { min: any; }) => string' is not assignable to type '() => string'.ts(2322)
locale.d.ts(18, 5): The expected type comes from property 'min' which is declared here on type 'YupLocale<StringLocale>'`

Answer (score 1):

DanishErrorMessages has type LocaleErrorMessages. Therefore, when you try to call its' methods, signatures from LocaleErrorMessages are being used. It means that every of your methods might be undefined. Here's how I solved your problem.

```
type LocaleErrorMessages = {
    required?: () => string | string
    email?: () => string | string
    passwords?: () => string | string
}

type DanishErrorMessages = LocaleErrorMessages & {
    email: () => string | string
    passwords: () => string | string
}

const d : DanishErrorMessages = {
    email: () => 'Tjek om du har skrevet din e-mail korrekt',
    passwords: () => "Kodeordet lever ikke op til kravene"}


d.email() // no error
d.required() //  errors
```

Basically, any variable of type LocaleErrorMessages could only be used with null checks:

```
const EnglishErrorMessages : LocaleErrorMessages = {email:..., passwords: ...}

if (EnglishErrorMessages.email !== undefined) {
  EnglishErrorMessages.email()
}
```

Try to think how are you goind to use your LocaleErrorMessages variables. If you have way some ts code that uses these methods to retrieve string and generate HTML code, how does it know that this exact locale has defined `required` field?

```
const userLanguageLocale : LocaleErrorMessages = getUserLanguageLocale()

const alertDiv = document.createElement('div')
alertDiv.textContent = userLanguageLocale.required() // compilation error
```

Therefore, LocaleErrorMessages type is probably useless with this approach. But with null check it makes more sense, since you can change behavior of your page depending on presence of some locales:

```
const userLanguageLocale : LocaleErrorMessages = getUserLanguageLocale()

const alertDiv = document.createElement('div')
if(userLanguageLocale.required !== undefined) { // if this locale is available
    alertDiv.textContent = userLanguageLocale.required() // no compilation error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific situation you may be able to use `Omit` and `Required`.

See [the Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Comment: Did actually try to make all required and then see if I could omit them, however that did not seem to work.

Comment: I think it may be more effective to first omit the field(s) you don't want to include and then make those remaining required. It would look something like this:

`type DanishErrorMessages = Require<Omit<LocaleErrorMessages, "required">>`

Comment: I just noticed your update. If it's done via interfacing, I think you may be able to just extend the interface and shadow the optional functions with mandatory functions? Haven't tested it but it's worth a shot.

This is where the difference between Type and Interfaces is relevant, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you're trying to achieve, you should rather make an `interface` - `ILocaleErrorMessages` that defines what method should be on the object.

`DanishErrorMessages` can be a class that implements interface. But throughout the application, you can use `interface` as a method/variable signature, but pass proper local language instance.

```
interface ILocaleErrorMessages {
    required?: () => string;
    email?: () => string;
    passwords?: () => string;
}

class DanishErrorMessages implements ILocaleErrorMessages {
    email() { return 'Tjek om du har skrevet din e-mail korrekt'};
    passwords() {return "Kodeordet lever ikke op til kravene" };
}

const localErrorMessages: ILocaleErrorMessages = new DanishErrorMessages();

// method `required()` is undefined, but does not break any code
const requiredMessage = localErrorMessages.required?.(); 
console.log("required message: ", requiredMessage);

const emailMessage = localErrorMessages.email?.();
console.log("email message: ", emailMessage);

const passwordMessage = localErrorMessages.passwords?.();
console.log("password message: ", passwordMessage);
```

Also, for the cases where function that returns message is `undefined`, you can use optional chaining operator`?.` - `func?.();`

TypeScript playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBkD2C4BsICiUUmUAshAM6VwDmVyA3gLABQyHyUEAjgK7BuAEwD8ALmQAKAJTIAvAD5klMFFC0A3G07IIAWzjBc4qbMXLV6re04AHONQDupIZRMz5SlWpCa2AXzY2BFwHSmQAETgQYEoACyIScioaenDgPVt8PQhwcIxsPEJiUgpqOgYWGw59Q1wPRi4IMD4oEGQAcgAVACsIAGtkTD1kIT5kOLgoZX7uADdm0dBdAFoDI2R+0m5+sA7-ax17JxdKBu4WtuQAIgBpTCEIF0X8Bengfv6UTFtkMA3ZnAFiAINdkAcAkFWAhMCAVMhcIVcIlSikKpQJAUcPgUclyml5MgQY5ItFYgkSnjUlQZNY2AB6enIHJgOIPZAAA24-EEECEMg5yFiyD4IEeMFAfIANMgAEZ8MCjTAMECYRWy7hwQbRACeyBhj2CsPh3IEwjK1MJiOxuIt6IAdKbeaJ7bTkEa4Zh8PbEbRJNcncJmWj6BJrjLA3y7fRpHTocbFbUjNGUHIEUjbSGqPak8ZXbGPZQvRAfZg-ddc8H8RAwzLcymC6xC4rjpRnFAhCmrRnKSnKPbW+3XCJ89YYZ7vb7-YOXFXqbXkDOOw240A).